# Как работать с ленивой инициализацией Spring + Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Класс User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "notes")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "NOTE_TIME")
@Column(name = "NOTE_TEXT")
private Map<Timestamp, String> notes = new HashMap<>();
/........../
}
```

Метод контроллера:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/notes")
public String notes(HttpSession session){
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    user.getNotes(); // - org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: esn.entities.User.notes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    return "notes";
}
```

Как мне инициализировать notes? Видел, что существует метод Hibernate.initialize(), но по-видимому в моём случае он не поможет. C бд работаю через EntityManager и признаюсь, плохо понимаю, как работают сессии hibernate.

**UPDATE:**

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/notes")
    @Transactional
    public String notes(HttpSession session){
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        User user2 = userDAO.getUserById(user.getId());
        Hibernate.initialize(user2.getNotes()); // - LazyInitializationException
        return "notes";
    }
```

UserDAO:

```
@Repository("user_dao")
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void persistUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        em.merge(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(Integer id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: `User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");` так это не работает. Сущность User в данном случае, вы должны были вытащить запросом через EntityManager, а не из HttpSession. Если приведёте более детальный код, могу попробовать разобраться.

Comment: У вас должно быть что-то вроде `User user =  entityManager.find(User.class, id);`

Comment: SpringNewbie, я обновил вопрос. А что конкретно нужно привести?

Comment: дошло до меня. это разные транзакции, поэтому и исключение

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю насколько этот подход правильный, но решил таким образом:

метод контроллера:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/notes")
    public String notes(HttpSession session){
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        User user2 = userDAO.getUserWithNotes(user.getId());
        session.setAttribute("user", user2);
        return "notes";
    }
```

Добавил специальный метод получения юзера с инициализированным списком notes:

```
Repository("user_dao")
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public User getUserWithNotes(Integer id){
        User user = em.find(User.class, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getNotes());
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Плохо, так сленивой иниациализацией не работают, ленивая она на то и ленивая что не требует инициализации.

Comment: вместо того, чтобы умничать, правильнее привести аргументы или оставить свой ответ. А в данном конкретном случае смысл ленивости в том, что пользователь в течении сессии может ни разу не обратиться к url - "/notes"